# ActiveAndroid schema migration DB version, can the version be incremented in parts?

Tags: android, sql, activeandroid

You all have probably seen that ActiveAndroid has schema migrations which are specified as `<db_version>.sql` files in the `assets/migrations` folder.

I have a db version **2**, with a migration file `2.sql`

Does my next version have to be **3** and migration `3.sql`, or can I do something like:

**DB version - 2.1**

Migration file: `2.1.sql` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it, it throw's an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

So I guess it has to be an integer.

But that raises another question, can I increment the version by two points instead of just one?

For e.g. migration1: **2.sql**
Migration2: **4.sql** ?

Comment: yes, you can increment the version by two points instead of just one.